# How do I define a default sort order for classes that I create in powershell?

Tags: powershell, class, sorting

I have created a small powershell class

```
Class StatSummary {
    [String] $name
    [int] $errors = 0
}
```

When I have a collection of instances of this class, I would like them to be sorted by default in ascending (or descending) order by $name. I find reference to **default sort properties** in the docs about Sort-Object but can't find an example of how to do it with my own class. Of course I can get the collection to sort differently by passing property names to Sort-Object but I would like to define a default as well. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the [`System.IComparable` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable) - it only requires one method, [`CompareTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto):

```bsh
Class StatSummary : IComparable {
    [String] $name
    [int] $errors = 0

    [int]
    CompareTo([object]$other)
    {
        return $this.name.CompareTo($other.name)
    }
}
```

In the example above, we simply compare on the `name` property:

```
PS C:\> 'Zoe', 'Andrew', 'Kate' |ForEach-Object {
>>   [StatSummary]@{ name = $_ }
>> } |Sort-Object |Select -Expand name
Andrew
Kate
Zoe
```

But you can do whatever you need, like sorting on `name`, then descending number of `errors`:

```bsh
[int]
CompareTo([object]$other)
{
    $n = $this.name.CompareTo($other.name)
    if($n -eq 0){
        return -$this.errors.CompareTo($other.errors)
    }

    return $n
}
```

Comment: That should work with compare-object as well, like datetime does.

Comment: @js2010 `Compare-Object` checks for equality, for that you'll want to override `[bool]Equals([object]$other){...}`

Comment: Maybe both then.  Compare-object sorts both lists.